# AngularJS, how to change value of a CSS animation rule?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-animations

I would like to change the value assigned to stroke-dashoffset basing on a custom input.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes donut-chart-1 {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100;
      }
    }

    @keyframes donut-chart-1 {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 100;
      }
    }
```

But with ng-class and neither ng-style I succeed in archive that.. Any idea?

Here a fiddle where the code is: [donut chart](http://jsfiddle.net/4azpfk3r/)

Thanks in advance!
Fabio

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is your problem? The code seems to work fine. Also, you don't need the webkit keyframes anymore.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, I have the percentage value hard coded in the CSS. Changing that value, the percentage of the donut chart changes too. So, if I want to change that 110 (75%) to a new one..how can I do in a angular webapp? Hope I clarified more my question..

Answer (score 2):

(*Tweak values to your benefit*)

1. Assign your `.donut-chart-1` stroke start off values. The value you need is  `ceil((radius of your circle)*2*Pi)`.

---

```
.donut-chart-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;  /* circumference of your circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440; /* set the offset, so you start with a gap, not the dash*/
}
```

---

2. Define the animation name, in this case `donut-chart-1` and the value for `stroke-dashoffset` to trigger the animation. The target value is `(your initial value) - (your initial value) * %`. Taking the above example, if you want to animate 90%, it would be `44` and 75% `110`.

---

```
@keyframes donut-chart-1 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 110; /* animates 75% */
  }
}
```

3. Impact the `.circle` element inside `.donut-chart-1` with the previously defined animation:

---

```
.donut-chart-1 .circle {
    animation: donut-chart-1 1s ease-out forwards;
}
```

---

You probably don't wanna mess with these values by hand, so you could use the following JS, to calculate the path lenght of your svg element, and set the values accordingly:

```
var path = document.querySelector('circle');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
```

Full snippet:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.item h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 125px;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.donut-chart-1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}

.donut-chart-1 .circle {
  -webkit-animation: donut-chart-1 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation: donut-chart-1 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes donut-chart-1 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 110;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item donut-chart-1">
  <h2>HTML</h2>
  <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle" r="70.14149" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additions Christoph, it was nice of you. Regards.

Comment: Hey Christoph, first of thanks for your answer! But I don't know if this is what I need, or maybe I didn't understand the javascript part.. What I need is to understand how technically, if possible, change values stored in stroke-dasharray, stroke-dashoffset, etc.. dynamically. For instance, from a input data set (json object) I have width, heigh. and in the HTML is easy to manipulate width just substituting the value with {{data.width}} ...how can I do the same with those values hardcoded in the CSS?!